# Random values consistent with a best-fit curve

Tags: random, statistics, probability, test-data

I'm contemplating the generation of test data with interesting distributions.

I understand methods for the generation of uniform distribution and normal distribution, but how can I transform an arbitrary function into a weighted distribution function?  My terminology may be off here - I won't mind corrections.

For example, let's say that I have a function over time which generally increases, but cycles periodically.   "Activity" which increases generally over a year, but weekly cycles with sharp falloff on the weekends.

The function could be algebraic, but it would be valuable if it could be any function (imperative(?) with discrete/discontinuous ranges(?)).

If the Activity curve from the example is `f(t)`, I could just make `f(t)` the mean and provide a fixed standard deviation, but how do I chose `t` if it too needs distribution?  I don't want to have to iterate through `T`, I just want to select among `T` randomly with the appropriate distributions.

So the TestActivityGenerator() function takes parameters for curves between, say, an absolute date range, another curve over weeks, and another curve over hours in the day, and spits out DateTimes in the proper distributions.  Results are *not* generated in any specific ordering.

Another scenario might be: a generator of reals which is, say, 1.652 times more likely to spit out a prime number than a composite.  No tricks on this one - there are trivial ways to do this, but I'm looking for a general solution.

Thanks!

Edit:  I've change the wording of the title to look at the problem from a different angle - How can we backtrack from a curve of best-fit to random samples that are consistent with that curve.  If I have a histogram of stock market data, how can I generate data that is distributed similarly to the real data.  Not just pairwise-values that average to the same value for each `t`, because they would fail other randomness tests.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you are trying to do. Can you give a concrete example? In general, you can turn any discrete set of values into probabilities by dividing each value by the sum of all the values.

Comment: Thanks @frankc.  The Activity is supposed to be the example.  Imagine each row entry with a datetime stamp is one Activity unit.  I want to generate 1 million+ rows of activity that are distrubuted consistently with f(t).  Perhaps I'm missing a trivial solution.

Comment: I'm still not really sure I understand, but is the main issue that you expect cycle/seasonality in your data and want to replicate that? If so, why not sample from different distribution functions depending on the date you are generating data for?

Comment: That'd be fine *if I had a date*.  I could determine a date's Activity count for the day.  But I don't have a date, and I don't want to iterate dates.  I want dates (and times) randomly chosen with a described bias from a range form say, years 2000 to 2010.

Comment: so why not just choose the date first from some distribution. Then map that date to one of some other set of other distributions based on your perceived cycles?